# sqlalchemy define calculated column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

how can I define in sqlalchemy a calculated column? 
The `date` column should be calculated from the `timestamp` column (which has a default, but can be set also by client)

Here is my table definition (mysql):

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`timestamp` as date)) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

here is my model, what should be in the `date` server default?

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    
    timestamp = db.Column(DateTime(), server_default = func.now())
    date = db.Column(Date(), server_default = <??>)
```

dd

Answer (score 0):

```
date = db.Column(Date(), server_default = func.date(timestamp))
```